# Can I run qemu on vps, not dedicated server? It seems that virtualisation not enabled. Is it possible?

Tags: windows-7, centos, virtualization, qemu, kvm-switch

TRying to run android virtual device on centos 7 64bit. AVD uses kvm to emulate android. I am on virtual private server not dedicated. So I am already inside kvm. Tried nested virtualisation but it didnt work. Is it possible to run kvm inside kvm?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but the VPS **host** needs to support nested virtualization – the guest cannot force it to be enabled. (When you're trying to enable it in your own qemu, it's for *offering* nested virt to your guest.)  This feature is currently still quite rare (especially among KVM hosts).